# error: expected declaration or statement at end of input Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: c, arrays

I'm writing a Tic Tac Toe Game. Now I'm developping a function which checks my array (Playboard).
I would like to change the interger uiWinner when someone has three x's or o's in a row but I'm currently getting the following error: expected declaration or statement at end of input

What can I do about it? I'm a beginner C programmer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char acBoard[3][3] =
{
    {'x', 'x', 'x'},
    {'o', 'x', '6'},
    {'7', 'o', 'o'},
};
unsigned int uiWinner = 0;
void is_there_a_winner(void);


int main()
{
    is_there_a_winner();
    printf("%d", uiWinner);
    return 0;
}


void is_there_a_winner(void) //kijkt naar het speelbord of iemand het 3 op een rij heeft
{
    //uiWinner 0 = niet
    //uiWinner 1 = Player
    //uiWinner 2 = PC

    if(acBoard[0][0] == 'x')
    {
        if(acBoard[0][1] == 'x')
        {
            if (acBoard[0][2] == 'x')
            {
                uiWinner = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if(acBoard[1][0] == 'x')
    {
        if(acBoard[1][1] == 'x')
        {
            if (acBoard[1][2] == 'x')
            {
                uiWinner = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if(acBoard[2][0] == 'x')
    {
        if(acBoard[2][1] == 'x')
        {
            if (acBoard[2][2] == 'x')
            {
                uiWinner = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if(acBoard[0][0] == 'x')
    {
        if(acBoard[1][1] == 'x')
        {
            if (acBoard[2][2] == 'x')
            {
                uiWinner = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if(acBoard[2][0] == 'x')
    {
        if(acBoard[1][1] == 'x')
        {
            if (acBoard[0][2] == 'x')
            {
                uiWinner = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    /* ********************************************* */


    if(acBoard[0][0] == 'o')
    {
        if(acBoard[0][1] == 'o')
        {
            if (acBoard[0][2] == 'o')
            {
                uiWinner = 2;
            }
        }
        if(acBoard[1][0] == 'o')
        {
            if(acBoard[1][1] == 'o')
            {
                if (acBoard[1][2] == 'o')
                {
                    uiWinner = 2;
                }
            }
        }
        if(acBoard[2][0] == 'o')
        {
            if(acBoard[2][1] == 'o')
            {
                if (acBoard[2][2] == 'o')
                {
                    uiWinner = 2;
                }
            }
        }
        if(acBoard[0][0] == 'o')
        {
            if(acBoard[1][1] == 'o')
            {
                if (acBoard[2][2] == 'o')
                {
                    uiWinner = 2;
                }
            }
        }
        if(acBoard[2][0] == 'o')
        {
            if(acBoard[1][1] == 'o')
            {
                if (acBoard[0][2] == 'o')
                {
                    uiWinner = 2;
                }
            }
        }




    }
```

Comment: Are you missing a closing `}`?

Comment: Yes I was missing a closing }. Thank you. Do you maybe have some advise for making this more compact?

Comment: Use loops so you don't need all those ifs. Also, no need to use a *global* variable. Have your function directly return the correct answer.

Comment: @Dennis　Determination is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to simplify the decision by express the player as a number.
The following specific examples

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef signed char board_state;
typedef struct {
    board_state board[3][3];
} Board;

typedef enum {
    Blank = -1, Player1, Player2, //Player1=0, Player2=1
    Unsettled = -1, Draw = 2
} Player;

#define Player_symbol "xo"

static void init_board(Board *b);//Initialization of the board
Player judge(Board *b);          //Current win-loss decision
void print_board(Board *b);

int main(void){
    Board b = {{   //Certain aspects
        { Player1, Player1, Player1},
        { Player2, Player1, Blank  },
        { Blank  , Player2, Player2}
    }};

    print_board(&b);

    Player winner = judge(&b);
    switch(winner){
    case Unsettled:
        printf("Victory or defeat is not determined.\n");
        break;
    case Draw:
        printf("Draw.\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("Winner %c.\n", Player_symbol[winner]);
    }
    return 0;
}
void print_board(Board *b){
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<3;++i){
        for(j=0;j<3;++j){
            board_state state = b->board[i][j];
            if(state == Blank)
                putchar(' ');
            else
                putchar(Player_symbol[state]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
static inline void init_board(Board *b){
    memset(b, Blank, sizeof(*b));
}

Player judge(Board *b){
    board_state *p = &b->board[0][0];
    if(
        (p[0] | p[1] | p[2]) == 0 ||
        (p[3] | p[4] | p[5]) == 0 ||
        (p[6] | p[7] | p[8]) == 0 ||
        (p[0] | p[3] | p[6]) == 0 ||
        (p[1] | p[4] | p[7]) == 0 ||
        (p[2] | p[5] | p[8]) == 0 ||
        (p[0] | p[4] | p[8]) == 0 ||
        (p[2] | p[4] | p[6]) == 0)
       return Player1;
    else if(
        (p[0] + p[1] + p[2]) == 3 ||
        (p[3] + p[4] + p[5]) == 3 ||
        (p[6] + p[7] + p[8]) == 3 ||
        (p[0] + p[3] + p[6]) == 3 ||
        (p[1] + p[4] + p[7]) == 3 ||
        (p[2] + p[5] + p[8]) == 3 ||
        (p[0] + p[4] + p[8]) == 3 ||
        (p[2] + p[4] + p[6]) == 3)
       return Player2;
    else if(
        (p[0] | p[1] | p[2] |
         p[3] | p[4] | p[5] |
         p[6] | p[7] | p[8]) == 1)
        return Draw;
    else
        return Unsettled;
}
```